# Android: Custom Login flow with Facebook

Tags: android, facebook-login, facebook-android-sdk

**Description:**
I've implemented Facebook SDK in my app to let user login with their Facebook account and was working well.. I wanted it to show a dialog to login and wanted to prevent Facebook app to be launched for login.
But this wasn't completely possible and don't gave me results as I expected.. 
I set LoginBehaviour to WEB_VIEW_ONLY but when you click on button it would first start Facebook app and you click back and click again on button to Login and then it will show popup.. 
Obviously this is a not expected behaviour.. I want to show popup and don't want to open Facebook app in any way.
So after some researches without finding anything related to my problem I wanted to implement my custom login flow using Facebook docs.. 
All went well and it is working as expected.. But now I need AccessToken for other Graph calls.. 
I got this AccessToken as a string from Facebook redirect URL after requesting for it when user logs in successfully so the returning URL contains AccessToken in it..
I have trimmed the URL removing the rest of the URL and keeping only token using substring..

**What I want:**
Now I want to use this string as AccessToken but I saw that I can't use it.. I need to convert the string to AccessToken otherwise I'm not able to use it..

**The issue:**
I don't know how to convert my string to AccessToken.. You can convert the AccessToken to string like `token.toString();` but can't do reverse operation.. 
So is there any way for me to convert or use this string as AccessToken or not?
Facebook stats:

```
public AccessToken(String accessToken)
```

Seems like AccessToken requires string.. But if I try to do the following:

```
AccessToken access = AccessToken.setCurrentAccessToken(accessTokenString);
```

It will say: Required AccessToken, found String.

Need help here. 
Thanks in advance